# Creating Tree Height Data from Bare Earth and Highest-Hit rasters

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.5, arctoolbox

I have two rasters I've downloaded: one is Bare Earth and the other is Highest Hit. Both contain elevation data.
I'm trying to calculate the difference between pixels which will give me the tree canopy height. Or in other words, subtract the Highest Hit from the Bare Earth pixel by pixel.

I was looking through ArcMap tool box and could not find any appropriate tool that would do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

Comment: what if I don't have access to Spatial Analysis extension? any other options?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not have a Spatial Analysis extension available to you at all or that you need help Activating the extension in ArcGIS?  If you do not have the extension at all you will need to do subtraction in QGIS or with GDAL (both open-source and free).

Comment: I don't have the extension at all. OK. I'll check out those sources. Thanks.

Comment: @GBG I was able to calculate the raster in QGIS, but when I try to add the results into ArcMap I receive the error message bellow. The tiff file appears in the map document, but when I look at the scale it does not make sense (1:3,030,453,885) that's one to 3 billion! I tried to reproject the file to different GCS but nothing seems to work.

"Waring, inconsistent extent!
One or more of the added layers has an extent that is not consistent with the associated spatial reference information. Re-projecting the data in such layer may lead to unexpected behavior."

Comment: That ESRI error is just a standard warning that the data you are adding is different that the CRS of the dataframe.  As for your projection/scale issue.  Best to post a screen shot of your QGIS parameters and of your ArcGIS desktop as a new question.